# Gulp-webserver : link to css doesn't work if outside the html folder?

Tags: html, css, server, gulp

If I have a html file and link to a css file that is in the same folder or a subfolder, the css is included when running gulp webserver.

But if I have the css file outside the html-folder, it doesn't get included.

So for example, if the css is in the same folder, I can write:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

and it will work. If I place it outside in the parent folder, and link to it:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">
```

it doesn't work. Is this a problem with gulp webserver or have I overlooked something? I would like to have the css at a diefferent place, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../builds/development/postcss/css/style.css">
```

In the browser, it says "failed to load resource".

Here is the webserver task:

```
gulp.task('webserver', function() {
    gulp.src(htmlFolder)
    .pipe(webserver({
        livereload: true,
        open: true
    }));
});
```

Comment: The `root` is the farthest back it can go: https://github.com/schickling/gulp-ebserver#usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `src` is the root of the server, you can't access it's parent due to security issues.

`gulp-webserver` does support middleware, such as `serve-static`.

```
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');

gulp.task('webserver', function() {
    gulp.src(htmlFolder)
    .pipe(webserver({
        livereload: true,
        open: true,
        middleware: [serveStatic(__dirname + '/builds')]
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way is to use the "browserSync" in nowadays.

```
function do_browserSync(done) {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: '.'
        },
        startPath: 'debug/index.html',
        port: 8000,
        open: true,
        notify: false
    });
    done();
};
```